# Ready-made animation libraries

Tags: .net, winforms, animation, progress-bar

I am looking for some progress animations to be shown in my WinForms application - so anything like AVI or animated GIF will do. The best would be animations depicting some "abstract" concepts, such as (for example) flying paper or animated 0s and 1s, to indicate progress.

I know that Visual Studio 2008 comes with its own animation library (Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary\1033\VS2008ImageLibrary.zip), but it is very small. Does anyone know of a website where I can find a sizable animation library with these requisites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your own loaders at http://www.ajaxload.info/